# Icon tabs' words is cut

Tags: react-native

In Samsung note 5 device, the words are cut. Any other way of doing this?

installed react-native-vector-icons, scrollable-tab-view

code:

```
<ScrollableTabView
                    renderTabBar={() => <DfyTabBar tabNames={tabNames} tabIconNames={tabIconNames} />}
>
...
</ScrollableTabView>

DfyTabBar class's render
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.goToPage(i)} style={styles.tab} key={tab}>
        <View style={styles.tabItem}>
                <Icon
                        name={this.props.tabIconNames[i]} // all icons
                        size={30}
                        color={color}
                 />
                <Text style={{color: color}}>
                        {this.props.tabNames[i]}
                </Text>
        </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is in most of the devices:

[image: most android devices View]

And this is in note 5:

[image: samsung note 5 View words cut]

Comment: <ScrollableTabView
                    renderTabBar={() => <DfyTabBar tabNames={tabNames} tabIconNames={tabIconNames} />}
>
...
</ScrollableTabView>